# AAPT: error: unexpected element <uses-native-library> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, zoom-sdk, zoom-meeting

I'm trying to update the Zoom SDK version in my React Native app to 5.11.3, but I'm encountering an issue when building the app.

I'm using the following configuration in my build.gradle file:

````
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 24
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31```

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.3'
    ...
}
````

When I try to build the app, I get the following error message:

````
AAPT: error: unexpected element ```<uses-native-library>``` found in <manifest><application>.
````

I believe this error is related to the Zoom SDK, as I did not encounter this issue before updating its version.

My question is: what is the minimum Gradle build tool version that supports ? And how can I fix this error and successfully build my React Native app with Zoom SDK version 5.11.3?

Thank you for your help!